# How to Properly Use Windows Phone 8 Store Test Kit

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have followed the directions on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394032(v=vs.105).aspx regarding the steps to ensure my application will pass the certification process. However, in the automated testing section the website shows a screenshot of the Store Test Kit, and at the bottom of the screenshot is a button that says 'Start Windows Phone Application Analysis'. I click this and attempt to run the first option, yet it seems to never stop. I have ran it for a few hours and then given up. Is this supposed to take this long? I am using the release build of my application, have completed the App Details portion, and ran the Automated Tests. It seems like the next step is to perform the 'Start Windows Phone Application Analysis' which I cannot seem to complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Windows Phone Application Analysis' is not an automated test utility. When you run it, it will launch the app and then the expectation is that you interact with / use the app while it logs details of the run. When you close the app it will generate a report based on what it recorded while it was being used.

Comment: Oh ok. I read that, but my app did not launch for some reason. Does it launch in the emulator or on my actual device? I was using the release build and had it going to my device. I'll try again later, thanks for response.